# Does a pointer point to a pointer with = or does it point to the original memory address. C++

Tags: c++, pointers, crash, scope

I have a question why my program crashes when I try to access a pointer to an object.  I want to select the object then get a pointer to it then store it in another object to manipulate it.

This is the code that is failing.  I use a pointer to get an object then before the function goes out of scope store that pointer in an object.  Does the pointer point to the original address or to the pointer that was sent to the pointer which is returned from.

This function crashed the program when the pointer goes out of scope.

```
void control::moveOrder(int a, int sp , bool al){

   h_AFV * ph_AFV;
   if(currentPlayer == 1){ph_AFV = pl1->gtAFV(marker);}
   if(currentPlayer == 2){ph_AFV = pl2->gtAFV(marker);} 
   ph_AFV->setStat(1); <-This works
   ph_AFV->setOrder('m'); 

   mvOrder m(ph_AFV, a, sp, al);   
   checker(ph_AFV);
   moving.push_back(m); 

   ph_AFV = NULL;
   delete ph_AFV; 
} // Added to make sense of constructor definition

mvOrder::mvOrder(h_AFV * pAFV, int d, int s, bool a){
  pMover = pAFV;
  azmuth = d;
  speed = s;
  align = a;
}
```

Comment: There isn't enough there to tell what is going on.  However, your `delete ph_AFV` does nothing, since it is always deleting a null pointer.

Comment: We need more information. Are `pl1` and `pl2` valid pointers? What does `gtAFV(marker);` do? What does `checker(ph_AFV);` do? You should be able to pinpoint what line it crashes on with a debugger.

Comment: Your title doesn't begin to make sense. Try rewriting it to express your actual problem.

Comment: If `currentPlayer` can be anything other than 1 or 2, this will have undefined behaviour due to an uninitialised pointer `ph_AFV`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Please also study how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)). 
 You have multiple globals — `pl1`, `pl2`, `currentPlayer`, `moving`, `marker`.  Have you validated that `currentPlayer` is always `1` or `2`, for example?  If it isn't, all hell is going to break loose.  You've diagrammed that `ph_AFV->setStat(1);` works; does that mean it is the `ph_AFV->setOrder('m');` that crashes, or you don't know?

Comment: P1 and p2 are valid pointers.  I tested t and they point to the original objects.  My problem is that the program crashes after the function goes out of scope.  I want to get a pointer from an array of objects in the pl1 or pl2 object.

Comment: Pl1 and Pl2 are valid pointers, I tested them and I inserted a message box before the function goes out of scope and it pops up and crashes right after I close the Box.